# How to extend toolbar.get.config.xml in Alfresco Share

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I'm trying to extend **toolbar.get.config.xml** in (share\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\site-webscripts\org\alfresco\components\data-lists).

For some reasons these is still done in pre v4.0 stile.

https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ALF-13592

Would be ideal to extend it via share-config-custom like other DocumentLibrary actions

Many thanks,
Rocco

Comment: What version of Alfresco are you using?

Comment: I'm using 4.1.1 btw. But that french blog pointed me to the right direction

Comment: Edited the question so is more easy for future people

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at this [french blog](http://charles.torda.net/2012/05/08/simplifier-la-configuration-des-actions-multiples-dans-share/) (use google translater if needed) and a lot will be clear.