# Alfresco multi-select action icon

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I am working on a custom action in Alfresco. I want the action to be available as both multi select and as well as action for each items. If I add new action I could see the icon. But in multi select the action icon is not displaying. How to display image to the multi select actions?

Here is my code:

Answer (score 1):

The OOTB multi-select actions for the Document Library can be found in the share-documentlibrary-config.xml file.

```
<multi-select>
     <action type="action-link" id="onActionDownload" icon="document-download" label="menu.selected-items.download" />
     <action type="action-link" id="onActionCopyTo" icon="document-copy-to" label="menu.selected-items.copy" />
     <action type="action-link" id="onActionMoveTo" icon="document-move-to" permission="Delete" label="menu.selected-items.move"/>
     <action type="action-link" id="onActionAssignWorkflow" asset="document" icon="document-assign-workflow" label="menu.selected-items.assign-workflow"/>
     <action type="action-link" id="onActionDelete" icon="document-delete" permission="Delete" label="menu.selected-items.delete" notAspect="hwf:hybridWorkflow,sys:undeletable" />
     <action type="action-link" id="onActionCloudSync" asset="document" icon="document-cloud-sync"  permission="CreateChildren" label="menu.selected-items.cloudSync" notAspect="sync:syncSetMemberNode" syncMode="ON_PREMISE" />
     <action type="action-link" id="onActionCloudSyncRequest" icon="document-request-sync" label="menu.selected-items.cloudRequestSync" hasAspect="sync:syncSetMemberNode" syncMode="ON_PREMISE" />
  </multi-select>
```

If you want additional multi-select actions to be displayed then you will want to augment this configuration attribute. Rather than editing this file directly you'll want to provide an extension to this particular configuration section (you can find some documentation of this [here](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/doclib-override-extension-examples.html))

It would be worth reviewing how the existing multi-select actions are implemented to ensure that your custom action is compatible as both a single item action and a multi-select action

Answer (score -1):

Looks like this is done by overwriting some of the ootb javascript, specifically the toolbar.lib.js and the toolbar.get.config.xml.

It's obfuscated in the title, but I believe this post answers your question:

[How to extend toolbar.get.config.xml in Alfresco Share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156806/how-to-extend-toolbar-get-config-xml-in-alfresco-share)

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to overwrite *anything* in Alfresco - most things are possible through configuration or extension and adding additional actions is no exception.